# Swagger documentation for REST response

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

Good afternoon.

I am trying to generate Swagger documentation but fails to generate clean result if the response is not a simple class.

if we consider a user with family members, the following REST function as a partial documentation

```
public ResponseEntity<FamilyMembersResponse> getUserFamily(@PathVariable("user_uuid") String UUID) {
    ...
    FamilyMembersResponse response= new FamilyMembersResponse(); 
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

By partial, I mean that swagger will say that result is of type FamilyMembersResponse (that is correct) but the FamilyMembersResponse class itself is not documented (return without any attributes).

The issue may be that the class FamilyMembersResponse is created within the controler but even with such definitions the class description is always empty:

```
class FamilyMembersResponse {
    @Schema(name = "user" )
    User user;
    @Schema(name = "family_members" )
    List<FamilyMember> family_members;

}
```

Any idea why? Issue seems "only" on the generation of FamilyMembersResponse "class", not the route

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer... as in simply posting in SO after looking for hours helped solving the issue (why, that is the question :D).

JsonProperty was expected, .. which kind of makes sense.

```
    @JsonProperty("user")
```